# What should be the R value of insulation for charcoal kiln?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am operating a charcoal kiln. The temperature of the kiln can reach around 800°C. What should be the R value of the required insulation? The outside temperature is around 30°C.

Comment: Consider the outside target temperature. Compare various materials and thicknesses. Make sure to choose materials that won’t combust.

Comment: The maximum temperature of the kiln will be reached when power in = power lost to ambient. So the R number really depends on how much heat you can afford to lose.